# What is a full name of my service/pod in Minikube?

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, stateless

I would like to configure a cluster of MongoDB nodes in my Minikube cluster.

The manual which I found assume to execute a following script in `mongosh` against first pod:

```
rs.initiate(
    {
       _id: "rs0",
       version: 1,
       members: [
          { _id: 0, host : "mongodb-deployment-0.mongo-service.default.svc.cluster.local:27017" },
          { _id: 1, host : "mongodb-deployment-1.mongo-service.default.svc.cluster.local:27017" },
          { _id: 2, host : "mongodb-deployment-2.mongo-service.default.svc.cluster.local:27017" }
       ]
    }
 )
```

Unfortunately, I am getting an error:

```
MongoServerError: No host described in new configuration with {version: 1, term: 0} for replica set rs0 maps to this node
```

It looks that the full hostnames do not exist in my Minikube cluster, because if I provide IP address of the nodes:

```
 rs.initiate(
    {
       _id: "rs0",
       version: 1,
       members: [
          { _id: 0, host : "10.244.0.3" },
          { _id: 1, host : "10.244.0.4" },
          { _id: 2, host : "10.244.0.6" }
       ]
    }
 )
```

it works fine.

I found that the hostnames are build in a following way: `pod-name.service-name.namespace.svc.cluster.local:port`, so my first command should work.

```
tom@macbook-air-tomasz-2 k8s-stateful % kubectl get pods
NAME                   READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
mongodb-deployment-0   1/1     Running   0          24m
mongodb-deployment-1   1/1     Running   0          22m
mongodb-deployment-2   1/1     Running   0          22m
```

```
tomaszbadon@macbook-air-tomasz-2 k8s-stateful % kubectl get service
NAME            TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)     AGE
kubernetes      ClusterIP   10.96.0.1    <none>        443/TCP     26m
mongo-service   ClusterIP   None         <none>        27017/TCP   26m
```

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: mongodb-deployment
  labels:
    app: mongodb
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongodb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongodb
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mongodb
        image: mongo
        ports:
        - containerPort: 27017
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /data/db
            name: mongo-volume
        env:
        - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mongodb-secret
              key: mongo-root-username
        - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
          valueFrom: 
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mongodb-secret
              key: mongo-root-password
        command:
          - mongod
          - "--bind_ip_all"
          - "--replSet"
          - rs0
  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: mongo-volume
      spec:
        accessModes: ["ReadWriteOnce"]
        storageClassName: demo-storage
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 1Gi
        
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongo-service
spec:
  ports:
    - name: mongodb
      port: 27017
      targetPort: 27017
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: mongodb
```

What are my full hostnames registered in Minikube dns, which could allow me to provide them in cluster configuration?

Thank you.